# CUDA on Fedora compilation failure

Tags: c++, cuda, fedora, nvidia

After looking at installing CUDA 5.0 on my new Fedora19 system, I found that CUDA 5.5 was a better candidate, as it came in an rpm format.  I followed the directions for installation found [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/howto_install_cuda_rpm_packages.txt), and everything was going great until I attempt to compile the samples.  First off, it installs the samples to /usr/local/cuda/samples, and I had to make sure that my LD_LIBRARY_PATH included /usr/local/cuda/lib (not just the 5.5 version), but then I get the following two errors when I attempt to run the 'make all' command.

```
../../common/inc/exception.h: In constructor ‘Exception<Std_Exception>::Exception()’:
../../common/inc/exception.h:129:94: warning: delegating constructors only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
Exception<Std_Exception>::Exception() :
```

I thought that C++11 was the default version?  And then when I get to trying to compile the matrixMulDrv, I get the following error that really makes no sense:

```
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++   -m64        -o matrixMulDrv matrixMulDrv.o  -L/usr/lib64/nvidia -lcuda
/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I was wondering if anybody else had any problems of this nature.  I had moved to 5.5 so that I could use the current gcc compilers (4.8.1).  When I look in /usr/lib64/nvidia, I see all of the files I supposedly need, including libcuda.so.1.  Has anybody else seen this?

Comment: Try "-std=c++11" if it tells you to

Comment: I will.  I need to find where it controls the overall flags and overwrite that particular flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora 18 with GCC 4.7.2/GLIBC 2.16 is an [officially supported distro](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_5/rc/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes.pdf) for CUDA 5.5 RC. Fedora 19 is not, nor is there any indication of support for GCC 4.8.x.  I'm not surprised you're having trouble. The `libcuda.so` you see in `/usr/lib64/nvidia` was linked against a different version of GLIBC (2.16) than the one that is [most likely on your machine](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/19/FeatureList) (2.17).

The only way forward with Fedora 19 that I can imagine would be to downgrade your (i.e. install an alternate) GCC/GLIBC to the one that comes with Fedora 18.  It might be easier just to switch to Fedora 18.

Comment: Ok, this is what I was afraid of.  I also screwed up my environment pretty badly, so I am going to reinstall Fedora19, and go from there.

Comment: You're not going to have any better luck if you re-install F19, unless you also plan to install (add on) a different GCC/GLIBC.  At the risk of repeating myself, you may have a better experience if you start with F18 instead.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  I am going to install Fedora 19, and then either load the different gcc/glibc (which is what I wound up doing on my mac), or simply waiting and seeing what happens.  It isn't necessary to my development right now, it would merely be awesome, as the cluster I intend to run on has a couple of tesla nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first issue:

```
../../common/inc/exception.h: In constructor ‘Exception<Std_Exception>::Exception()’:
../../common/inc/exception.h:129:94: warning: delegating constructors only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
Exception<Std_Exception>::Exception() :
```

These messages are only warnings, so compilation should still continue without problems.

Regarding the second issue:

```
/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

have a look in /usr/lib64/nvidia and ensure that libcuda.so and libcuda.so.1 symlinks both exist and point to libcuda.so.[your driver version].

In my installation, the /usr/lib64/nvidia/libcuda.so symlink was not created, for whatever reason. If yours is also missing, then type (as root):

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/nvidia/libcuda.so.VERSION /usr/lib64/nvidia/libcuda.so
```

replacing *VERSION* with the version number of your nvidia driver (for example libcuda.so.319.32).

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  I will let you know how this works.  I think I simply screwed up a part of the install, or got inconsistent drivers installed in the same area.

Comment: If you want to work around the errors you are seeing, I should have pointed out that if you *only* include `/usr/local/cuda/lib` in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH and *not also* `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`, you will have trouble as well, building 64 bit apps.  It's possible that that is the only issue, based on your description.  But I still don't know if that is enough to make it work, or if you will run into compatibility problems on F19 with cuda 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

[CUDA is highly specific to the Linux kernel version](http://news.crosscompute.com/post/112727815757/cuda-requirements-are-strict).  For example, CUDA 6.5 is only guaranteed to work with [Fedora 20 kernel 3.12](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=494712).

```
# Install kernel 3.16.2
sudo yum -y install https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/kernel/3.16.2/201.fc20/x86_64/kernel-3.16.2-201.fc20.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum -y install https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/kernel/3.16.2/201.fc20/x86_64/kernel-devel-3.16.2-201.fc20.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum -y install libvdpau-devel
sudo reboot

# Install cuda 6.5
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_5/rel/installers/cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run
sudo bash cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run --override
```

It can be helpful to downgrade your kernel to match the version specified in the [CUDA System Requirements](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/#system-requirements).